# Redux component and useEffect for timer logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

So, I have a functional component with a couple of text boxes (Name and Timer i/p box display) and Start/Stop buttons.

I want that;

1. When Start is clicked, timer box should count and show seconds passed.
2. When Stop is clicked, name and time should be saved to redux store and timer i/p box should go back to zero. (Saved values for name/timer are displayed below as part of another component)
3. When focus is on timer box, timer should stop/pause
4. When we focus out/blur from timer box, timer should resume from that point.

I have added my code to sandbox in the below link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-tp7pv?file=/src/TestComponent.js

Some part of relevant code highlighted below as well. Essentially, I wanted to understand, if I am going right by using the useEffect to update the timer box?
Any suggestions to improve the approach?

```
export const TestComponent = (props) => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ id: 0, taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
  const [stopTimerEvt, setStopTimerEvt] = useState(true);
  //var timerId;

  useEffect(() => {
    var seconds = 0;
    var interval;
    if (stopTimerEvt === false) {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
        setTask((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, timeField: seconds++ };
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [stopTimerEvt]);

  const startTimer = () => {
    setStopTimerEvt(false);
    /*
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      setTask((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, timeField: seconds++ };
      });
    }, 1000);
    */
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    //clearInterval(timerId);
    setStopTimerEvt(true);
    props.saveTask(task);
    setTask((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, timeField: 0 };
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTask((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="taskName"
        value={task.taskName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        id="timeField"
        value={task.timeField}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button id="start" onClick={startTimer}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button id="stop" onClick={stopTimer}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { saveTask })(TestComponent);
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some of the changes you need to make in the `TestComponent`:

```
export const TestComponentNew = (props) => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
  const timer = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => stopTimer();
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(function () {
      setTask((v) => ({ ...v, timeField: +v.timeField + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    timer.current = null;
    props.saveTask(task);
    setTask({ taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTask((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="taskName"
        value={task.taskName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="task name"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        id="timeField"
        value={task.timeField}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button id="start" onClick={startTimer}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button id="stop" onClick={stopTimer}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Here is the Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

`EDITED`

```
export const TestComponentNew = (props) => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
  const timer = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => stopTimer();
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(function () {
      setTask((v) => ({ ...v, timeField: +v.timeField + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    timer.current = null;
    props.saveTask(task);
    setTask({ taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTask((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="taskName"
        value={task.taskName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="task name"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        id="timeField"
        value={task.timeField}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handlePause}
        onBlur={startTimer}
      />
      <button id="start" onClick={startTimer}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button id="stop" onClick={stopTimer}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...You seem to be quite close....However, just a few points...I need the time/count to be displayed in the 2nd timer textbox...I need the focus and blur events on this 2nd timer textbox and want to stop/focus on focus and resume timer on blur...Also, when Stop is clicked, name and time should be saved to redux store and timer i/p box should go back to zero

Comment: I added the changes you mentioned in https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-tp7pv?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

Comment: So, essentially...a bit confused about the state management for the timer input box...
Would the value be set to {task.timeField} or {seconds} as per your code ?

<input
        type="number"
        id="timeField"
        value={task.timeField}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

Comment: @testndtv I didn't understand exactly what's the point of `timeField input` is, so I change the demo a bit, do you mean this? https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

Comment: So..the input box would show the seconds...and on stop btn click, I want the task name (1st box) and seconds/timer (2nd box) to be displayed below as part of my current state...

Comment: @testndtv ok, I think I'm kinda getting your point here, but why do you need an input to show the `timer`? just show it as I show the `seconds` state

Comment: @testndtv I've edited the answer and the demo, try to see if this is what you need

Comment: Awesome yes...you seem to be in the right direction now...Again, this is just for learning purpose...so yes, please don't think about the actual application....Only thing we now need to add is the event handling for focus and blur on the time box (as highlighted in points 3 & 4 in the original question)

Comment: @testndtv good, So if the answer is helpful, try to accept the answer and give it an upVote

Comment: @testndtv sure, let me check it

Comment: @testndtv is this what you need? https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

Comment: @testndtv https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

Comment: @testndtv it works fine for me try to open it in `incognito mode` https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js

Comment: Tried in incognito mode as well this link https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js....Still not pausing when focus is on 2nd textbox...so if current count is 5 and I focus on this tex box, it should stay at 5 and resume from 5, when we blur from this text box

Comment: @testndtv you're not clicking on my link, I've forked the code and edited. try using the link I pasted above. I will also change the code in my answer too,

Comment: Oh k...got it...yes, this one seems to be perfect https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-forked-pfrb3?file=/src/TestComponentNew.js....I just have a final question...could you explain the reasoning for the useRef hook...Is it to just prevent re-rendering...i mean if we would have used setState instead ?

Comment: So essentially, how/when do we decide to use useRef v/s useState?

Comment: @testndtv you took almost 5 times more time than the actual time I put aside for answering a question :)))) . just come on to my profile and give some upVotes randomely :)) so I get the return from time investment :)))

Comment: @testndtv about your last question. all you need to do is read this article and you good to go https://www.linkedin.com/posts/taghikhavari_useref-vs-usestate-should-we-re-render-or-activity-6749617264120619008-_A9q